# Point of overloaded constructor in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor-overloading

I am having trouble understanding exactly what this piece of code is useful for

```
class buildArgs:
    def __init__(self, host, port, user, dept):
        self._dept = dept
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._user = user
        self._datacenter = datacenter
        self._path = path
    def __init__(self): 
        self._dept = None
        self._host = None
        self._port = None
        self._user = None
        self._datacenter = None
        self._path = None
```

This is then followed by a bunch of @property methods followed by setters like so  and then the main method:

```
@property
def port(self):
    return self._port
@port.setter
def port(self, port):
    self._port = port
```

I've never seen two `__init__` functions under a class in Python before and am assuming this is unpythonic. What is the correct approach for this type of logic?

Comment: The two `__init__` definitions look like a mistake. The second definition would supplant the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What that code does is equivalent to not defining the first `__init__` at all (it just gets replaced by the second immediately, and it is never seen again).

You could get something similar to both behaviors by only using the first constructor, and giving all parameters a default of `None`:

```
def __init__(self, host=None, port=None, user=None, dept=None):
        self._dept = dept
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._user = user
```

which would also allow for providing some arguments, but not all. For more complicated cases, define an alternate constructor as a [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) (class methods exist primarily to implement alternate constructors), where it converts (or provides) its own arguments to the ones expected by the primary constructor, then ends with `return cls(expected, arguments, here)`:

```
class buildArgs:
    def __init__(self, host, port, user, dept):
        self._dept = dept
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._user = user

    @classmethod
    def from_the_void(cls):
        return cls(None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks for the help! It seems I need to brush up on my understanding of class methods as well.